# How to add previously deleted CSV columns in Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, power-query

After you use Power Query to load a CSV file, it only shows the columns you chose when you first created the query.

What if you suddenly want to start using a column you previously deleted in the query?

While Power Query's Advanced Editor can be used to modify the code that controls that, is there an easy way to do so through the UI?

For example, if you previously removed the dummy column from the following CSV file, and now you want it back:

| Name | ID | dummy | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1234 | 1 | 324234 |
| Steve | 1230 | 2 | 124536 |
| Deb | 1293 | 3 | 968578 |

Compare to Text Import where all you have to do is click Edit on the query and run the wizard again.

[image: Excel's Text Import Wizard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Power Query window includes an **Applied Steps** pane where you can review and edit the query. You can select the step where you removed the column and either edit it (click gear button next to step name) or delete that step and re-create it.

Comment: I've accepted but it's - not your fault, of course, a non user friendly to do so, what with having to track the specific step

Comment: Thanks. I come at it from the other end of the telescope - it's amazing for me to have a WYSIWYG data transformation tool, where you can jump to any step and see how the data looks before and after.

Comment: The Applied Steps is great! But it doesn't mean there shouldn't be a straightforward way to do what this question asks. Also, it doesn't seem to solve [cases of adding brand new columns](https://superuser.com/questions/1497174/how-to-add-new-csv-columns-in-power-query).

Comment: You could post or upvote it as an idea here: https://excel.uservoice.com/

Comment: Good Idea, [done](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/38941408-an-easy-way-to-add-csv-columns-to-an-existing-powe)!

Answer (score 0):

in power query,

1. select the step where you removed the columns (especially if you removed multiple in one go)
2. then go to view tab at the top of power query
3. select advanced editor
4. delete the column name you wish to restore from the "Removed Columns" step and click Done

your column will be reinstated to the table. easiest win!

Don't forget to go to the data tab and select refresh all to ensure the changes are reflecting across your work book after you exit power query using save and load.